# Video and Audio keeps restarting when condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino, arduino-uno

***Functionality:***

I have made use of Arduino to sense a user proximity. And when proximity is sensed, arduino will detect and return a "1". There is a delay of 4 seconds: meaning a return  of 4 "1"s before, the video that is playing will restart and accompanied with the video's audio.

When user moves away, arduino will detect and return a "0". There will be a delay of 3 seconds: meaning 3 "0"s before the video's audio is mute, while the video will continue to play. Meanwhile, for added user experience, even when user is there but happens to fidget such that the arduino detects and returns a "0", the video with audio is suppose to continue without running the function of stop Audio, unless there is a return of 3 "0"s.

***Issue:***

I have managed to achieve the following:

1.) video replays with audio when arduino returns 4 "1"s
2.) audio is mute but video will continue to play when arduino returns 3 "0"s

However this is the issue that I am currently facing:

1.) I am not able to get video with audio to continue playing when arduino returns at least a "0" or 2 "0"s before the condition of 3 "0"s. The video with audio will be interrupted and when user is still within the proximity, video will restart with audio.

This is no the behaviour that i am looking for.
Correct behaviour flow:

- User proximity sensed: arduino returns 4 "1"s, video will restart with audio. When user fidgets, arduino returns a temporary "0", video with audio will still continue to play. however, when user leaves, arduino returns 3 "0"s, audio will mute while video will continue to play

Code:

```js
function getFeedback() {
  //To call on ajac getFeedBack
  ajax_getArduinoFeedback("flash.do", "formType=getArduinoFeedback");
}

//To stop interrupt method and reset fields to original
function stop_interrupt() {
  isInterrupt = false;
  triggerFeedback = "0";

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#M_Video").jPlayer("mute", true);
  }, 3000);
  //console.log("stop_interrupt triggerFeedback: " + triggerFeedback );          
}

//Interrupt method to call on refresh method
function show_interrupt(flag) {
  //Set Timeout for flag to be equal to "1"
  isInterrupt = true;
  isPlay = false;
  triggerFeedback = flag;

  if (flag == "1") {

    Flag = setTimeout(function() {


      if (triggerFeedback == "1") {
        //Display digital alert

        console.log("4 seconds later");
        console.log("flag: " + triggerFeedback);

        //Clear Timeout value of flag="1"  when current flag
        clearTimeout(Flag);

        //Clear Timeout value of flag ="0"
        clearTimeout(Absent);

        if (isPlay == false) {
          isPlay = true;
          $('#smell_background').fadeIn({
            duration: slideDuration,
            queue: false,
            complete: function() {

              $('#smell_text').fadeIn({
                duration: slideDuration,
                queue: false
              });
              //Smell-Image to fadeOut after delay
              setTimeout(function() {
                $('#smell_text').fadeOut({
                  duration: slideDuration,
                  queue: false
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#smell_background').fadeOut({
                    duration: slideDuration,
                    queue: false
                  });
                }, 900);
              }, 4000);
            }
          });

          setTimeout(function() {
            //Restart video

            $("#M_Video").hide();

            $("#M_Video").jPlayer("setMedia", {
              m4v: "lib/video/video_03.mp4"
            }).jPlayer("play");
            $("#M_Video").jPlayer("mute", false);

            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#M_Video").fadeIn();
            }, 2500);
            console.log("videoList:" + videoList[videoIndex]);
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    }, 2000);
  } else if (flag == "0") {

    isPlay = false;
    clearTimeout(Flag);
    console.log(isPlay + "1");

    Absent = setTimeout(function() {
      if (triggerFeedback == "0") {
        clearTimeout(Flag);
        isPlay = false;
        console.log("flag: " + triggerFeedback);

        console.log(isPlay + "2");
        if (isPlay == false) {
          console.log(isPlay + "3");
          stop_interrupt();
        }
      }
    }, 5000);

  }
}

//Method call when data from Arduino is "1"
function interrupt(flag) {
  console.log("isInterrupt : " + flag);
  //location.reload();
  if (isInterrupt == false) {

    if (triggerFeedback != flag) {
      if (triggerFeedback == "1" && flag == "0") {
        //stop_interrupt();
        show_interrupt(flag);
      } else {
        if (flag != "0") {
          //console.log("1");
          show_interrupt(flag);
        }
      }
    } else {
      //console.log("2");
      show_interrupt(flag);
    }
  } else {
    if (triggerFeedback != flag) {
      if (triggerFeedback == "1" && flag == "0") {
        //stop_interrupt();
        show_interrupt(flag);
      } else {
        if (flag != "0") {
          //console.log("3");
          show_interrupt(flag);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false">

  <div id="M_Start" align="center" class="M">

    <!--Video Div-->
    <div id="M_Video" style="position:absolute; z-index:99; left:-80px; top:0px;"></div>
    <!--Alert background-->
    <img id="smell_background" class="Smell_Cask" src="lib/img/Smell_Background.png" />

    <!--Alert Text-->
    <img id="smell_text" class="Smell_Cask_Text" src="lib/img/Smell_Text.png" />

  </div>

</body>
```

//Arduino Code:

```
const int trigPin = 8;
const int echoPin = 9; 
//Motor-Fan connected to arduino pin number
const  int FanPin = 5;

long duration;
int distance;

void setup() 
{
pinMode (FanPin , OUTPUT) ; // Set pinMode for FanPin as OUTPUT, display  
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); // Open serial port to communicate with the Ultrasaonic Sensor
}

void loop() 
{

digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);

digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

distance= duration*0.034/2;

if(distance < 20)
{
  //delay a time of 2 seconds  before writing Print of '1' and set Motor fan to HIGH
  delay(1000);

  // Write a pin of HIGH
  Serial.println("1");
  //Set motor-fan to operate
  digitalWrite (FanPin, HIGH);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("0");
  //Set motor-fan to stop
  digitalWrite (FanPin, LOW);
}
delay(100);
}
```

What have I done wrong or missing? Please help.

Comment: I miss the point, code is missing, what does javascript have to do with arduino, what video, what audio, you're question is not properly written

Comment: @MarkoMackic, sorry about that. i have uploaded the codes. I have made use of arduino to run the function in javascript via an an ajax call

Comment: Again this question is not properly asked, what does js has to do with arduino, what is the interaction , I see only serial port as source of comunication , how do you read sp, what does ajax have to do with this, what language is what. you're code is almost unreadable, comments are unclear, how do you read ultrasonic sensor(if that's ordinary ultrasonic sensor that's not a way to handle it) , so I don't think we're gonna answer your question easily

Comment: @MarkoMackic  I am using js to run a jplayer. And furthermore, I am using arduino to control the play of the video in jplayer. As stated in the question, if senses proximity, video in jplayer will restart, else will continue to play. Serial port is just read from COMPORT, usb connection of arduino with the PC. Ajax is used to call on the data that has been sent from the arduino, acts a link. So when arduino returns a binary output of either 1 or 0, the ajax will read and cache it as data which will be run by the javascript

Comment: @MarkoMackic the ultrasonic sensor reads based on the wavelength and the distance you set in the arduino code, if it can detect a presence, it will return a '1', else, it will always return a '0'

Comment: I know what US is, and I'm still not following what are you using to read serial port data.

Comment: @MarkoMackic, I am just using an arduino-uno board which is connected to the PC via a USB comport. if I am not mistaking your doubt. I have a backend code in java that reads the output given by the arduino.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118275/discussion-between-marko-mackic-and-luke).

Comment: There is not enough info to answer your question, sorry, I can't ask that many questions any more, you must give your code a rework for others to easier read it, and understand it

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the interrupt function needs to be VERY short. I would also like some clarification and some current code. But the way I undestand your question I think you need shorter interrupt function.

The interrupt should only set a global value based on the sensor value and thats it.

Comment: I have updated code. Please have a look, sorry about the missing codes. was in a rush to do something else. hence overlooked on uploading the code

Comment: what do you mean that the interrupt function needs to be very short?

Comment: He'd thinking about arduino interrupts, and you're not using that anywhere

Comment: Yes, sorry. First time i read it, I understood it like an interrupt function that could not finnish.